# Download official android LinkedIn APK

Tags: android, apk, linkedin-api

I am following the developers guide for integrating LinkedIn in my android app. [Android SDK guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk)

Now for integrating LinkedIn you need to have the LinkedIn app installed for it to work. You are pointed to a [downloadpage](https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#mobilesdk) for the LinkedIn apk file and install it on your emulator, because that's what I'm working with.

I can't find the LinkedIn apk file on that page. Only sdk files and another apk file of a sample app. And whenever I try to install a linkedin apk downloaded from apkmirror.com .

It gives me the error:

> INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

Does you guys know what this means? Any experience with the linkedin integration?

Comment: The problem is your app uses ARM architecture and the device or emulator that you are trying to install the app support otherwise such as x86. Try installing it on ARM emulator. Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

In Android Device Manager create a new device and select a profile with play store enabled. There is literally a checkmark with a PlayStore icon.